# customed command not found in a new terminal

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

everyone.

I had a basic question want to consult, about the environment variable setting.
After closed my one existed terminal which could execute compile(make) and do customed(mksdboot) command, i can't do mksdboot command anymore(I had execute a predefined setting environment variable shell script i.e. $ . ./arndale_envsetup.sh again) in the new terminal.

Cause i am a beginner in Linux, i am not very clearly about the environment variable setting rules.
i had tried to 'su' or 'sudo' to execute mksdboot, but no luck:(

ps. I had another project needs to compile in my PC(i didn't export PATH to .bashrc, only execute export PATH when i open a new terminal every time), may it efforts the original project's environment variable?

thanks.

**[UPDATED]**

i tried using $source ./arndale_envsetup.sh, relative commands worked finally. 
but i still did't figure out the reason between work or not work. >"<

Comment: So the commmands make and mksdboot worked for you, then you closed the terminal and they don't work any more? Is that right?

Comment: I would try su - which sets the variables appropriately for root. And googling for mksdboot.

Comment: to Thorsten Staerk: yes. you are right.

Comment: In the past, I opened a new terminal and executed the arndale_envsetup.sh all the relative commands are set. I don't know why this time it just failed:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
history
```

will list what your previous commands where.

This might give you a pointer what set the path in the way you needed it.

You could also try to see where you command is via

```
locate mksdboot
```